# How to set gcc option -march?

Tags: gcc

I get the help of `gcc -march` by typing `gcc --target-help` command:

```
-march=CPU[,+EXTENSION...]
   generate code for CPU and EXTENSION, CPU is one of: i8086,
   i186, i286, i386, i486, pentium, pentiumpro, pentiumii,
   pentiumiii, pentium4, prescott, nocona, core, core2,
   corei7, l1om, k6, k6_2, athlon, k8, amdfam10, generic32,
   generic64 EXTENSION is combination of: 8087, 287, 387,
   no87, mmx, nommx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2,
   sse4, nosse, avx, noavx, vmx, smx, xsave, movbe, ept, aes,
   pclmul, fma, clflush, syscall, rdtscp, 3dnow, 3dnowa,
   sse4a, svme, abm, padlock, fma4, xop, lwp
```

I tried to set `-march=i686+nommx` and `-march=i686,+nommx`, but it's not correct! `gcc` reported error: `error: bad value (i686,+nommx) for -march= switch`

I want to build my program to `i686` without `mmx` target, how to set the `-march` option?

Comment: i686 isn't in the list you provided, so just out of curiosity, what happens if you use something that is explicitly listed?

Comment: What is your version of `gcc` ?

Comment: I have resolved this problem. it should be passed to assembler by using -Wa,-march=i686+nommx.

Comment: I think that march=i686 doesn't enable mmx, according to table in gcc/gcc/config/i386/i386.c "`{"i686", PROCESSOR_PENTIUMPRO, CPU_PENTIUMPRO, 0},`" (there is no `PTA_MMX` flag here), it is alias for pentium pro which was released without MMX feature.